# Cannot read property 'counterHub' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to make a simple user counter with `SignalR`, but for unknown reasons to me I am getting this error in the console. I am very new to signalR and asp.net, but what I have make sense to me, and I don't know why am I getting the error. Can somebody please help me solve this and possibly explain why it is happening?

Here is the code in the Index view.

```
<div class="row">
Number of online users <strong id="counter"></strong>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var counterHub = $.connection.counterHub;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        });
        counterHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
            $("#counter").text(count);
        }
    });

</script>
```

The hub class :

```
public class CounterHub : Hub
{
    static long counter = 0;
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        counter = counter - 1;
        Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    //public void Hello()
    //{
    //    Clients.All.hello();
    //}
}
```

And the Startup.cs :

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();

            ConfigureAuth(app);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `counterHub` somewhere else?

Comment: No, I don't use it anywhere else. I posted all the code where it may be encountered

Comment: What is you visual studio version?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi 2015 Community edition

Comment: Please test this code to your global file: hubRoute = RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

Comment: add `[HubName("counterHub")]` before `public class CounterHub : Hub{}`....

Comment: @FarzinKanzi , can you demo how exactly should I do that. Because when i copy/paste your code it's underlined with red and I am not sure how to act in this case.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, thanks, just tried it, but it did not work.

Comment: @RobertRoss i edited my answer. Please test the new one.

Comment: I made it work for anyone who is interested. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but this made it work for me finally. I just surrounded the script tags with `@section scripts` :

```
    @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            var myHub = $.connection.counterHub;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            });
            myHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
                $("#counter").text(count);
            }
        });

</script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your chat files in the root of application?

The only thing that I think is your page has not connected to Hub proxy javascript file:

> ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v1.0.0

This file has some methods to connect to hub, consists:

```
$.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
    var proxies = {};
    this.starting(function () {
        // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
        // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
        registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

        this._registerSubscribedHubs(); .......
```

That lack of this method caused your error:

> Cannot read property 'counterHub' of undefined

Because it can not connect to hob and create objec named **counterHub**.

So please test this: After loading your application in another tab of your browser test this url:

> Your-App-Url/signalr/hubs

That in local host is some thing like this:

> http://localhost:53398/signalr/hubs

And see if you get the javascript file or not. If not I suggest you to start another project(If it is test).

Comment: It is the same as before ( underlined with red) and on hover it says : 'SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection)' is obsolete : 'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR in an owin startup class.'

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs; I referenced those in the hub class, which, i believe, is enough.